# Escape special regex character in string

Tags: php, regex

I want to escape special characters from a string that contains regex.  Is there any solution in PHP or did I have to do it myself?

Expected input:

```
.*
```

Expected output:

```
\\.\\*
```

I tried to search for it, but I found no results.

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
$string = ".*";
$string = preg_quote($string, '/');
print $string; // output: \.\*
```

The `'/'` parameter must match the delimiter you're using for your pattern.

Comment: It's quite handy to specify the second parameter depending on the delimiters you will use in your regex.

Answer (score 2):

Put it between `\Q` and `\E`. This escapes the character in between them.

Comment: Unless the characters in between are from an unknown source (like a user entered string), in which case it might contain a `\E` character. Use `preg_quote` instead.